# Multiplying each element of a numpy array and summing it up

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, X and y. X is of size m, and y is of size n. I need to multiply each element of y by every element of X, and then sum up.

Something like `[sum(X[0]*y) sum(X[1]*y) sum(X[n]*y)]`

This is what I mean

```
np.sum(X[:, np.newaxis] * y, axis=1)
```

However typically X and y are really large and so doing

```
X[:, np.newaxis] * y
```

creates a huge temporary array, which blows up stuff. Is there a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're multiplying each element of `y` by every element of `X`, just multiply all the elements of `X` together first, then use multiply the array `y` by this number and sum:

```
num = X.prod()

(num * y).sum()
```

Edit: the array you specify can be obtained by multiplying the array `X` by the sum of the elements of `y`:

```
X * y.sum()
```

Comment: Thanks but this definitely not equivalent to `np.sum(X[:, np.newaxis] * y, axis=1)` . I want a 1d array like `[sum(X[1]*y), sum(X[2]*y), sum(X[3]*y)]` and so on.

Comment: Ah. In that case, does `X * y.sum()` return what you want?

Comment: ah damn it. it does. this was a really dumb question.

Comment: No worries - I've often spent ages trying to figure out something that had a simple solution in the end

Comment: @Manoj - the answer should be up to date now